# Nikon Vertical Shutter Button Switch

Tags: nikon

I've always wondered why the switch around the vertical shutter button on Nikon pro digital bodies and battery grips is backwards?

On the main on/off switch, you rotate the switch clockwise to turn it on, but the vertical switch rotates counter-clockwise to the on position.

Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical release lock switch matches the operation of the directional pad lock ring or lever on bodies that have them.  What the lock and power switches have in common is that you turn them clockwise to engage whatever feature they provide.  The power switch enables the entire camera and the vertical shutter lock switch enables the vertical shutter lock.

You'll also find that the shape of the body around the switch makes it much more difficult to accidentally push the switch into the locked position, preventing you from releasing the shutter if you need to.  Having the same blob on the other side would make using the vertical shutter release awkward.

Comment: I see, now that makes sense. I find it interesting that they consider locking the shutter release the feature, where I find the feature to be the use of the shutter release. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to lock it when using your camera horizontally and supporting the lower edge with your palm or other surfaces would trigger the shutter.